# How to use the get_values(nodes) method in OPCUA Python ? What is the 'nodes' data format?

Tags: python, client, opc-ua, siemens

In OPCUA Python, what is the format/data structure of ***nodes*** parameter which we pass to the get_values() method ?

My node id  is : "ns=2;s=/Plc/DB190.DBD88:REAL"

```
from opcua import Client

client = Client("Server Address")
client.session_timeout = 3000

client.connect()

node_ids = ["ns=2;s=/Plc/DB190.DBD24:REAL",  "ns=2;s=/Plc/DB190.DBD28:REAL",
           "ns=2;s=/Plc/DB190.DBD32:REAL",]

## I want to use client.get_values(nodes) method
## What is the data format of 'nodes' parameter ?  i.e. nodes = ?
## How to store my 'node_ids' in 'nodes' ?
## I want to obtain values of node_ids in one shot.
```

This node_id is as per Siemens Sinumerik Format

Answer (score 0):

Yes this format is supportet. You can always test the NodeId in UAExpert. If you can read the value via UAExpert, than you can use the nodeid, here as well.

Do you get an error?

This call gets all the values in one call.

```
node_ids = ["ns=2;s=/Plc/DB190.DBD24:REAL",  "ns=2;s=/Plc/DB190.DBD28:REAL",
           "ns=2;s=/Plc/DB190.DBD32:REAL",]
client.get_values(node_ids)
```